# Postgres error from active record joins

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord, refinerycms

Rails 3.2 Refinery 2.0.10

I have a basic association between my engines where

```
Work
  belongs_to client

Client
  has_many works
```

In my controller I have a method that should give me a list of works from a specified client (myClientName), but I'm getting a postgres error that says im missing a from clause:

```
target = "myClientName"
::Refinery::Works::Work.joins(:client).where(client: {title: target})
```

And the error:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "client"
```

I don't think my problem is the query because it is constructed almost identically to the example in the active record docs:

```
time_range = (Time.now.midnight - 1.day)..Time.now.midnight
Client.joins(:orders).where(orders: {created_at: time_range})
```

I thought it might be a namespacing issue but the sql statement seemed to be looking at the right tables.  By no means am I a sql guru but I don't see anything wrong with the sql generated by active record:

```
: SELECT "refinery_works".* FROM "refinery_works" INNER JOIN "refinery_clients" ON         "refinery_clients"."id" = "refinery_works"."client_id" WHERE "client"."title" = 'myClientName'
```

Any idea what could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Looking closer to your query:

```
SELECT "refinery_works".* 
FROM "refinery_works"
```

The Inner JOIN here refers to `refinery_clients`

```
INNER JOIN "refinery_clients" ON "refinery_clients"."id" = "refinery_works"."client_id"
```

Here you are trying to use a `client` table attribute

```
WHERE "client"."title" = 'myClientName'
```

So essentially, the query is wrong.
Possible things that could make this problem happen:

Is the client model making reference to another table? `self.table_name = 'refinery_clients'`?

Try changing this part, `.where(client: {title: target})`
to something like this, `.where('refinery_clients.title = ?', target)`
or, if you happen to really use a table called `client`, `.where('client.title = ?', target)`